# Flutter file word readable

Tags: flutter, dart, file, permissions, filesystems

I want to write a file with flutter, that has got the same function as WORLD_READABLE in android. So i want tha this file can be read by all the applications.
More clear: i have an app A that write hello.txt i want that another app B can read this file. How i should set my file? There is a parameter of some function in the package path_provider?

I seen the package path_provider and File class, but i didn't find something.
I have already tried by access direct to file from app B, but is not world readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work and make sure you use the latest path_provider dependency. getExternalStorageDirectory() does the trick!

```
//Write file from App 1

 import 'dart:io';
 import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
    
 Future<void> writeToFile(String data) async {
   final directory = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
   final file = File('${directory.path}/hello.txt');
   await file.writeAsString(data);
    }

//Read the written file from App 2

import 'dart:io';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

Future<String> readFromFile() async {
  final directory = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
  final file = File('${directory.path}/hello.txt');
  return file.readAsString();
}
```